# Install orchis-gtk theme on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: themes, 14.04

I am trying to install the orchis-gtk theme on Ubuntu 14.04.
http://mokaproject.com/orchis-gtk-theme/download/

It said 'Orchis requires the Murrine engine for it's GTK2 aspects.'

What does that mean? Do I just need to do this from the website or I need to do more?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/orchis-gtk-theme
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install orchis-gtk-t
```

Answer (score 2):

The designer/developer here.

"Orchis requires the Murrine engine for it's GTK2 aspects" is just a notice of it's dependencies.

But since it's being installed via a package manager instead of from the source, you needn't worry about it as it'll be done automatically.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install orchis-gtk-theme
```

Comment: He ignored you. That's sad. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have installed this (beautiful) theme, and all that is required are the above commands. There is an Ubuntu-specific distribution page, which I assume you found since you have the commands from that page. For those looking for it, 
http://mokaproject.com/orchis-gtk-theme/download/ubuntu/

Note, however, that you must use

```
sudo apt-get install orchis-gtk-theme
```

Instead of what you have above,

```
[incorrect]sudo apt-get install orchis-gtk-t
```

which I assume was a typo